# How to have a circular reference in pyomo.dae?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to solve the following equation using pyomo.dae:

[image]

Solving the PDE including only the first 3 terms works properly by as follows:

```
m = ConcreteModel()

# Defining parameters
m.D= Param(initialize = D)
m.v = Param(initialize = v)
m.Re = Param(initialize = Re)
m.v_var = Param(initialize = v_var)
m.u = Param(initialize = u)

#Defining space/time grid
m.x = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,L))
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,t_end))

#Definig solution space
m.C = Var(m.t, m.x)

#Defining partial derivatives
m.dCdt   = DerivativeVar(m.C, wrt=m.t)
m.dCdx   = DerivativeVar(m.C, wrt=m.x)
m.d2Cdx2 = DerivativeVar(m.C, wrt=(m.x, m.x))

@m.Constraint(m.t, m.x)
def pde(m, t, x):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    if x == 0 or x == L:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.Re * m.dCdt[t,x] + m.v * m.dCdx[t,x] - m.D * m.d2Cdx2[t,x] == 0
```

The problem that I encounter is adding the fourth term since it includes 'C' which is the solution. I add this term as follows:

`return m.Re * m.dCdt[t,x] + m.v * m.dCdx[t,x] - m.D * m.d2Cdx2[t,x] - m.Re*m.v_var*m.C[t,x] == 0`

The above function returns a circular reference error when running:

`SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(m, tee=True)`

I know that it can be solved since the equation has an analytical solution.

Any thoughts how can I integrate into the PDE the solution variable?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to declare the PDE which contains its own solution would be as follows:

```
return m.Re * m.dCdt[t,x] + m.v * m.dCdx[t,x] - m.D * m.d2Cdx2[t,x] == -m.Re * m.v_var * m.C[t,x]
```

and not:

```
return m.Re * m.dCdt[t,x] + m.v * m.dCdx[t,x] - m.D * m.d2Cdx2[t,x] - m.Re*m.v_var*m.C[t,x] == 0
```